# Scalability issue during link establishment in Orient DB

Tags: java, orientdb, document-database

Here we are using orientDB to deal with large amount of data.
    We created a document database first: (CREATE DATABASE remote:localhost/test root password plocal document). Then we have created two Class C1 and C2 in Orient DB. Then, we have dumped around 100k records from external RDBMS to each of these class C1 and C2. Now, we want to establish Link with a command say: CREATE LINK L_VIEW TYPE LINKSET FROM C1.COLUMN_ID TO C2.COLUMN_ID. Surprisingly, this Link establishment operation is taking infinite time (5 hours+). We have tried this experiment multiple times in high-configuration m/c, increased JVM memory etc. but no luck.

Appreciate if anybody can provide any guidelines on this scalability issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you created index against the fields? Look at documentation: http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Import-From-RDBMS.html